# How to solve "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" error in custom query in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 and I want to show the result data of my query in my blade view. But I've got an error :

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

It seems ok if I used the query builder from laravel like :

```
$surat = new Surat();
$surats = $surat->select('name', 'age', 'sex')->get();
$data_surat = ['surat' => $surats];
return view('profile', $data_surat);
```

But, if I am using custom query like the query below, I've got the error.

```
$surats = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT `name`, `age`, `sex` from `surat`") );
$data_surat = ['surat' => $surats];
return view('profile', $data_surat);`
```

Do you know how to solve it? I need to use a custum query tho.